# get radio checked values and switch div without reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

My first question here. I have two option groups, when I use the selected option of two groups, I expect the page to show result div ( without the page reloading )

My code is below

```
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/220x120" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
        <input type="radio" name="location" vaule="vn" checked>Viet Nam
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/220x120" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
        <input type="radio" name="location" vaule="us">US
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/220x120" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
        <input type="radio" name="location" vaule="eu">Europe
    </label></div>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default active">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/220x120" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
        <input type="radio" name="type" vaule="bikers" checked>bikers
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/220x120" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
        <input type="radio" name="type" vaule="cars">cars
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/220x120" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
        <input type="radio" name="type" vaule="planes">planes
    </label>  
</div>
```

I want, eg location == vn AND type == biker ==> replace div id=result by div id=vnbiker
or if location == eu AND type = cars ==> replace div id=result by div id=eunotplanes

When any radio button is changed, the result div should change too (without a page reload).

Comment: Can you post the code & what you currently have working on JsFiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/60/

i added `<div id="result">vn + bikers</div>` to the html

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').on('change', function() {
        var resultArray = [];
        $('input:radio').each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked') == true) {
                resultArray.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
        $('#result').html(resultArray[0] + ' + ' + resultArray[1]); //or whatever you want to put here
    });
});
```

pretty much what the js is doing is on change of any radio button, it searches through and finds the checked radio buttons and pushes their values into an array, then it puts those two values in div with id="result".

**also note: in your markup, you spelled value wrong ("vaule" is how its spelled in the question for all 6 radio button inputs).

hope this helps!

EDIT: to help you with your new requirements, i created a loop which iterates through the result array i previously set up. see demo: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/68/

different code:

```
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            html += resultArray[0];
        }
        else {
            html += ' + ' + resultArray[i];
        }
    }
    $('#result').html(html);
```

Comment: Now i got another issue. If i have over two group radio, the js doesn't work anymore. IF i need js change the result only with name=location and name=type, how can i do it?

Comment: @TienNguyen check out the edit to my answer :] hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications to your code, and added the necessary to make it a full HTML file, here it is:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function clk () {
 if ( ( document.getElementById("vn").checked == true ) &&
      ( document.getElementById("bk").checked == true ) )
    { document.getElementById("result").style.cssText =
         document.getElementById("vnbiker").style.cssText;
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
        document.getElementById("vnbiker").innerHTML;
      return;
    }
  if ( ( document.getElementById("eu").checked == true ) &&
      ( document.getElementById("cr").checked == true ) )
    { document.getElementById("result").style.cssText =
         document.getElementById("eunotplanes").style.cssText;
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
        document.getElementById("eunotplanes").innerHTML;
    }
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="vnbiker" style="background-color:green;">div vnbiker</div>
 <div id="eunotplanes" style="background-color:orange;">div eunotplanes</div>
 <!-- ABOVE IS MY NEW CODE -->
 <!-- BELOW IS YOUR CODE, I ADDED "ID" AND "ONCLICK" TO RADIOBUTTONS -->
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label class="btn btn-default active">
         <img src="https://placehold.it/220x120" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
         <input type="radio" name="location" value="vn" id="vn" onclick="clk();">Viet Nam
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-default">
         <img src="https://placehold.it/220x120" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
         <input type="radio" name="location" value="us" checked id="us" onclick="clk();">US
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-default">
         <img src="https://placehold.it/220x120" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
         <input type="radio" name="location" value="eu" id="eu" onclick="clk();">Europe
     </label></div>
 <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
     <label class="btn btn-default active">
         <img src="https://placehold.it/220x120" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
         <input type="radio" name="type" value="bikers" checked id="bk" onclick="clk();">bikers
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-default">
         <img src="https://placehold.it/220x120" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
         <input type="radio" name="type" value="cars" id="cr" onclick="clk();">cars
     </label>
     <label class="btn btn-default">
         <img src="https://placehold.it/220x120" class="img-responsive img-rounded">
         <input type="radio" name="type" value="planes" id="pl" onclick="clk();">planes
     </label>  
 </div>
 <!-- BELOW CODE IS MINE -->
 <div id="result" style="background-color:magenta;">div result</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```